# vanilla javascript to Reactjs component?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, d3.js

I have a little vanilla javascript code, and am hoping to convert it into a React component. I really dont know where to begin, and I have a few questions that seem be very simple.

First, how do i even get started converting this to React? Do i place all of these variables in the constructor, or in the render (before the return) Is all of this inline styling sufficient, without any external CSS?

This is the class (d3-based KMeans clustering visualization):

```
var flag = false;
var WIDTH = d3.select("#kmeans")[0][0].offsetWidth - 20;
var HEIGHT = Math.max(300, WIDTH * .7);
var svg = d3.select("#kmeans svg")
  .attr('width', WIDTH)
  .attr('height', HEIGHT)
  .style('padding', '10px')
  .style('background', '#223344')
  .style('cursor', 'pointer')
  .style('-webkit-user-select', 'none')
  .style('-khtml-user-select', 'none')
  .style('-moz-user-select', 'none')
  .style('-ms-user-select', 'none')
  .style('user-select', 'none')
  .on('click', function() {
    d3.event.preventDefault();
    step();
  });

d3.selectAll("#kmeans button")
  .style('padding', '.5em .8em');

d3.selectAll("#kmeans label")
  .style('display', 'inline-block')
  .style('width', '15em');

var lineg = svg.append('g');
var dotg = svg.append('g');
var centerg = svg.append('g');
d3.select("#step")
  .on('click', function() { step(); draw(); });
d3.select("#restart")
  .on('click', function() { restart(); draw(); });
d3.select("#reset")
  .on('click', function() { init(); draw(); });


var groups = [], dots = [];

function step() {
  d3.select("#restart").attr("disabled", null);
  if (flag) {
    moveCenter();
    draw();
  } else {
    updateGroups();
    draw();
  }
  flag = !flag;
}

function init() {
  d3.select("#restart").attr("disabled", "disabled");

  //var N = parseInt(d3.select('#N')[0][0].value, 10);
 //var K = parseInt(d3.select('#K')[0][0].value, 10);
 var N = 700;
 var K = 9;

  groups = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < K; i++) {
    var g = {
      dots: [],
      color: 'hsl(' + (i * 360 / K) + ',100%,50%)',
      center: {
        x: Math.random() * WIDTH,
        y: Math.random() * HEIGHT
      },
      init: {
        center: {}
      }
    };
    g.init.center = {
      x: g.center.x,
      y: g.center.y
    };
    groups.push(g);
  }

  dots = [];
  flag = false;
  for (i = 0; i < N; i++) {
    var dot ={
      x: Math.random() * WIDTH,
      y: Math.random() * HEIGHT,
      group: undefined
    };
    dot.init = {
      x: dot.x,
      y: dot.y,
      group: dot.group
    };
    dots.push(dot);
  }
}

function restart() {
  flag = false;
  d3.select("#restart").attr("disabled", "disabled");

  groups.forEach(function(g) {
    g.dots = [];
    g.center.x = g.init.center.x;
    g.center.y = g.init.center.y;
  });

  for (var i = 0; i < dots.length; i++) {
    var dot = dots[i];
    dots[i] = {
      x: dot.init.x,
      y: dot.init.y,
      group: undefined,
      init: dot.init
    };
  }
}


function draw() {
  var circles = dotg.selectAll('circle')
    .data(dots);
  circles.enter()
    .append('circle');
  circles.exit().remove();
  circles
    .transition()
    .duration(500)
    .attr('cx', function(d) { return d.x; })
    .attr('cy', function(d) { return d.y; })
    .attr('fill', function(d) { return d.group ? d.group.color : '#ffffff'; })
    .attr('r', 5);

  if (dots[0].group) {
    var l = lineg.selectAll('line')
      .data(dots);
    var updateLine = function(lines) {
      lines
        .attr('x1', function(d) { return d.x; })
        .attr('y1', function(d) { return d.y; })
        .attr('x2', function(d) { return d.group.center.x; })
        .attr('y2', function(d) { return d.group.center.y; })
        .attr('stroke', function(d) { return d.group.color; });
    };
    updateLine(l.enter().append('line'));
    updateLine(l.transition().duration(500));
    l.exit().remove();
  } else {
    lineg.selectAll('line').remove();
  }

  var c = centerg.selectAll('path')
    .data(groups);
  var updateCenters = function(centers) {
    centers
      .attr('transform', function(d) { return "translate(" + d.center.x + "," + d.center.y + ") rotate(45)";})
      .attr('fill', function(d,i) { return d.color; })
      .attr('stroke', '#aabbcc');
  };
  c.exit().remove();
  updateCenters(c.enter()
    .append('path')
    .attr('d', d3.svg.symbol().type('cross'))
    .attr('stroke', '#aabbcc'));
  updateCenters(c
    .transition()
    .duration(500));}

function moveCenter() {
  groups.forEach(function(group, i) {
    if (group.dots.length == 0) return;

    // get center of gravity
    var x = 0, y = 0;
    group.dots.forEach(function(dot) {
      x += dot.x;
      y += dot.y;
    });

    group.center = {
      x: x / group.dots.length,
      y: y / group.dots.length
    };
  });

}

function updateGroups() {
  groups.forEach(function(g) { g.dots = []; });
  dots.forEach(function(dot) {
    // find the nearest group
    var min = Infinity;
    var group;
    groups.forEach(function(g) {
      var d = Math.pow(g.center.x - dot.x, 2) + Math.pow(g.center.y - dot.y, 2);
      if (d < min) {
        min = d;
        group = g;
      }
    });

    // update group
    group.dots.push(dot);
    dot.group = group;
  });
}

init(); draw();
```

Any help in understanding (or or course providing converted code) would be so helpful.

Comment: Variables should become member variables of the React component class and functions become class methods. Then put function excution codes inside the render function. It would be neat to have external CSS but not necessarily. https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. If you're beginning from scratch, set up a boiler plate.For e.g `create-react-app`
2. Install `d3` library in this project
3. Create a component for this and import and render that component in your `app.js`
4. Make these variables as part of the `state` of the component and `method` inside the component as class methods